# Can i make hyperledger fabric permissioned-public

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am building identity management system and i want to make it permissioned-public like fabric-indy.some people suggest me to use hyperledger indy but i want to build permissioned-public system upon hyperledger-fabric which is permissioned-private. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could expose dedicated a REST API for the functions you want to be public and start this instance of the REST server with a business network card with the appropriate rights.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean "permissioned-public". There are 3 types of blockchain: Public, meaning anybody can join, Permissioned, meaning you need a permission to join, and Private, meaning it runs on your desktop or an intranet. By "join" I mean add a node to the blockchain.

If, on the other hand, you want to provide a public gateway to the blockchain, this is possible with the provided REST server or a custom backend, but we're back to a centralized system in this case. Meaning you have a single point of failure/hack, plus people have to trust your software, which makes it no better than a traditional SaaS.